# How to reduce accordion summary height MUI - React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create an accordion using "@mui/material" library. Currently having issues fixing the height of AccordionSummary.

I tried bellow solutions. these solutions dint work for me.

1. setting sx property and having height:"0"
2. adding inline styles
3. setting disableGutters to true
4. taking classes by inspecting and changing there styles

Bellow are screenshots for better understanding , I am trying to reduce the space between hi text

[image]

code

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./InventoryTrackingHeading.css";
import { BsChevronDown } from "react-icons/bs";
import Accordion from '@mui/material/Accordion';
import AccordionSummary from '@mui/material/AccordionSummary';
import AccordionDetails from '@mui/material/AccordionDetails';

const InventoryTrackingHeading = () => {
const [isDemoDetailAccOpen, setIsDemoDetailAccOpen] = useState(false);

const InventoryTrackingTitle = [
    {
      title: "test",
      value: "test",
    },
    {
      title: "test",
      value: "test",
    },
        {
      title: "test",
      value: "test",
    },
];

return (
    <>
     <Accordion   TransitionProps={{ timeout: 0 }}>
            <AccordionSummary
              aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
              id="panel1bh-header"
              className="accSummary"
              expandIcon={<BsChevronDown />}
             
            >
          <div>hi</div>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
        <div className="demo-detail-container">
            {InventoryTrackingTitle?.slice(3).map((rowData, index) => (
              <div key={index} className="box">
                <div className="form-label">{rowData["title"]}</div>
                <div className="value">{rowData["value"]}</div>
                </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </AccordionDetails>
    </Accordion>
    </>
  );
};

export default InventoryTrackingHeading;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following styles to AccordionSummary.

`sx={{ minHeight: "0px", ".MuiAccordionSummary-content": { margin: 0 }, }}`

Comment: thanks for that, but in expand i still see the issue though